# Python - Generalized Linear Models Coefficients

Tags: python, regression, spline, coefficients

I am comparing  different regression models (linear, polynomial and splines) in Python to get the slope's coefficients of a log-log [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShxPn.png), and to interpolate new curves later.

I am using the last piece of code here, ( Ctrl+ 'Generating natural cubic spline') : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-regression-splines-python-codes/) and I printed the [summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Lcl.png) corresponding to my set of data.

My question : Are the coefficient written in the summary the slope's coefficients or is it something else related to the statistic model GML (binomial regression in this case)?

Here is the code:

```
from patsy import dmatrix
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Generating natural cubic spline
transformed_x3 = dmatrix("cr(train,df = 3)", {"train": X_train}, return_type='dataframe') 
fit3 = sm.GLM(y_train, transformed_x3).fit()

# Prediction on validation set
pred3 = fit3.predict(dmatrix("cr(valid, df=3)", {"valid": X_valid}, return_type='dataframe'))

xp = np.linspace(3e+04, 5e+06, 50)
pred3 = fit3.predict(dmatrix("cr(xp, df=3)", {"xp": xp}, return_type='dataframe'))

print (fit3.summary())
```

Thank you in advance for your help !